# Permanently changing color of tool/output in ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I have a pretty complex model in ModelBuilder, and I'd like to custom-color certain tools and outputs. I'm not so fond of the orange-green-blue scheme that is there by default.

However, when I change the color of one of the blocks using 'display properties,' the color is changed back to the default whenever I validate the model.

Is there any way to make the color change permanent?

Comment: Are you using ModelBuilder with the ArcMap or ArcGIS Pro application of ArcGIS Desktop?

Comment: @PolyGeo Desktop